# Do Cobalt support "qual-e"(YouTube Qualification Engine) page?

Tags: cobalt

1. Can cobalt enter the YouTube Qualification Engine page?
   (http://2016.qual-e.appspot.com/)
2. If yes, how can I enter this page for testing?

Answer (score 2):

qual-e.appspot.com has been updated and the main pages should work properly now. I just confirmed with Cobalt 10.49488, its able to render the Home and Conformance pages.

Not all sub-pages have been updated, see this bug for details: [issuetracker.google.com/issues/35339754](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35339754)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can open Qual-E in Cobalt. Run Cobalt from command line with the following parameters:

```
./cobalt --allow_http --csp_mode=disable --url=http://qual-e.appspot.com/?enableLogs=1
```

While the page won't render correctly (YouTube certification team is working to fix that), you can see the results in terminal or Cobalt developer console (press Ctrl-O twice and restart Qual-E).

Here is the sample output:

```
[1209/152344:INFO:console.cc(49)] [console.log()] Fri Dec 09 2016 15:23:44 GMT-0800 (PST) - [AudioContext] - result: AudioContext supported
[1209/152344:INFO:console.cc(49)] [console.log()] Fri Dec 09 2016 15:23:44 GMT-0800 (PST) - [AudioContext] - value returned: [object AudioContext]
```

Cobalt team is aware of several gaps between Cobalt feature set and YouTube TV Technical Requirements and going to address them in Q1 2017.