# Cobalt needs to upgrade EME APIs

Tags: cobalt

We found why we can playback the purchased videos of YTTV, but cannot test EME website. Because `SourceBuffer::appendBuffer` is used in 2017 EME test website, but YTTV home page can automatically select the old API if `SourceBuffer::appendBuffer` does not be implemented.

EME 2017 test website: 
http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/unit-tests/2017.html?test_type=encryptedmedia-test

Answer (score 1):

Cobalt team is aware of the need to upgrade the supported EME version, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41070502/1318869.

In the meanwhile, for the purpose of testing of Starboard player implementation, try running youtube.com/tv in Cobalt and play any purchased video.