# could cobalt load qual-e page "http://2016.qual-e.appspot.com/"?

Tags: cobalt

We checkout latest cobalt source code, version "Import Cobalt 8.21796", and it built successfully.

cobalt can load Youtube TV page "www.youtube.com/tv?launch=menu" and works fine.

Currently, we want to load "http://qual-e.appspot.com/?enableLogs=1" for YouTube Qualification but we got cobalt crashed message.

```
Caught signal: SIGILL (4)
  starboard::shared::signal::(anonymous namespace)::Crash() [0x89dbf3]
  <unknown> [0x7fc1330e2330]
  SbSystemBreakIntoDebugger [0x89b4aa]
  logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0x6f196c]
  cobalt::css_parser::yyparse() [0x1c02d55]
  cobalt::css_parser::ParserImpl::Parse() [0x1bc092d]
  cobalt::css_parser::ParserImpl::ParsePropertyValue() [0x1bc1787]
  cobalt::css_parser::Parser::ParsePropertyValue() [0x1c0d02c]
  cobalt::cssom::CSS::Supports() [0x46ea108]
  cobalt::cssom::(anonymous namespace)::staticfcn_supports() [0x365f30a]
  <unknown> [0x7fc11a210be0]
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Cobalt support "qual-e"(YouTube Qualification Engine) page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034920/do-cobalt-support-qual-eyoutube-qualification-engine-page)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug either in qual-e or Cobalt.

I would suggest filing a bug at Cobalt's public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:181120%20status:open

Comment: thanks for your response, we posted it at [35339754](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35339754).

Comment: hiDavid, it seem no progress on this issue, could someone help us to push it? or have other way to display qual-e page?
we had test latest cobalt (Import Cobalt 9.34413), it still crash.

Comment: Hi, I know... I am expecting this to be fixed before the end of April