# Do Cobalt support “qual-e”(YouTube Qualification Engine) page?

Tags: youtube, cobalt

During the Youtube 2017 certification test (https://qual-e.appspot.com/) on the Cobalt(version_9.28152.) ported to my platform, I encountered the following symptoms.

- Qual-E test : `./cobalt --allow_http --csp_mode=disable --url=https://qual-e.appspot.com/`
  -> result  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gguv.jpg][1]

  1. Are these test results correct?
  2. If I'm wrong, I wonder why and what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Cobalt support "qual-e"(YouTube Qualification Engine) page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034920/do-cobalt-support-qual-eyoutube-qualification-engine-page)

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt engineers has a task to make it can be supported with cobalt, see the [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35339754), ETA of this task is 4/21 from googlers.

Comment: is ETA of this work  definitely the 21day?
I tested but got the same error.